# How do I use an inner array from an Observable on *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript

Previously I had a simple object representing a user's properties, however as I need to add paging to my table visualization, I created a view model class with a member of type User (my model). Here's the code:

users-grid.ts (view model)

```
import { User } from "../../models/user";

export class UsersGrid {
    rowCount: number;
    pageCount: number;
    pageSize: number;
    page: number;
    data: Array<User>;
}
```

user.ts (model)

```
import { Role } from "./role";

export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    role: Role;
}
```

Then I'm using these classes from my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { UsersGrid } from "../viewModels/users/users-grid";
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class UsersSearchService {

    private baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/users`;  // URL to web api

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    search(term): Promise<UsersGrid> {
        console.log("A");
        return this.http
            .get(this.baseUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("B")
                return response.json() as UsersGrid;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

That is consumed by my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersSearchService } from "./users-search.service";
import { UsersGrid } from "../viewModels/users/users-grid";

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'users-search.component.html',
    providers: [UsersSearchService]
})
export class UsersSearchComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    users: Observable<UsersGrid>;
    private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(
        private usersSearchService: UsersSearchService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    search(term: string): void {

        // Push a search term into the observable stream.
        this.searchTerms.next(term);
    }


    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.users = this.searchTerms
            .debounceTime(300)        // wait for 300ms pause in events
            .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
            .switchMap(term => this.usersSearchService.search(term))
            .catch(error => {
                // TODO: real error handling
                console.log(`Error in component ... ${error}`);
                return Observable.of<UsersGrid>();
            });


    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.search("");
    }
}
```

The problem is that after adding the view model class and changing the type of the users variable in my component (last code block), the service method is not executing (console.log("A") is not executed).

Can't I use a complex type like my view model as an observable?

### UPDATE

I think I found the cause of this problem, so I'm updating the question title as I'm still looking for a fix.

The problem seems to be related to the `*ngFor` attribute when I try to use `users.data`, because if I remove the `.data` the service is invoked but causes an error and if I add it back, the service is not invoked and no error message is shown.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users.data | async">
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.role.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How did you call `search(term)`? any error message?

Comment: Sorry, now I saw that the service code was duplicated and the component was missing. I call `search(term)` from `ngOnInit` and no error message is added to Chrome DevTools console.

Comment: I updated the question. The problem seems to be related to the inner array that I'm trying to use on `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to this. Here's what I had to do:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of (users | async)?.data">
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.role.description}}</td>
</tr>
```